# Replace multi chars - regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

i trying to do if there are more then one - in my string its replace to a single - eg.

`---` replace to `-`

or `test---demo` replace `test-demo`

**my function is**

```
function strconvert( str ) {
  var ret = str;

  ret = ret.replace( /ø/g, 'oe' );
  ret = ret.replace( /Ø/g, 'OE' );
  ret = ret.replace( /å/g, 'aa' );
  ret = ret.replace( /Å/g, 'AA' );
  ret = ret.replace( /æ/g, 'ae' );
  ret = ret.replace( /Æ/g, 'AE' );
  ret = ret.replace( /\_/g, '-' );

  ret = ret.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/-]/ig,'-').replace(/_+/ig,'-').toLowerCase();

  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace( /-+/g, '-' );`

```
ret = ret.replace( /-+/g, '-' );
```

**Update :**  You can combine `.replace(/_+/g,'-').replace(/-+/g,'-')` to `.replace(/[_-]+/g,'-')`

Comment: @ParisNakitaKejser : glad to help

Comment: Now i only need to trim on - in start and end of my string :P can you help here to?

Comment: @ParisNakitaKejser using replace with regex you can do `.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );` or you can use `trim()`